# Have div fill in remaining space between left and right elements that DONT have fixed width

Tags: css

Ok... so I know there are lots of similar questions out there about how to fill in the remaining space between two divs.  However, none of them will work for me because I need to not count on the elements to the left and the right side always being the same width.  I hope that makes sense.

Here is my html:

```
<section id="recent-news-posts" class="light-gray-section">
    <h1>
        <div class="h1-first">
            Recent
        </div>
        <div class="h1-second">
            NewsPosts
        </div>
    </h1>
    <div class="line">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="green-button">Read All News</div>
    <div class="content">
        Content
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is the css that I currently have:

```
.light-gray-section {
    background-color:#e4e0db;
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
}

    .light-gray-section h1 {
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        font-weight: 500;
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        margin:0px;
        float:left;
    }

        .light-gray-section h1 .h1-first {
            color:#142114;
            display:inline;
        }

        .light-gray-section h1 .h1-second {
            color:red;
            display:inline;
        }

    .light-gray-section .line {
        display:inline-block;
        height: 45px;
        width:100px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #9ec096;
    }

    .light-gray-section .green-button {
        float:right;
        /* IE10 Consumer Preview */ 
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4C9444 0%, #2D5E27 100%);
        /* Mozilla Firefox */ 
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4C9444 0%, #2D5E27 100%);
        /* Opera */ 
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4C9444 0%, #2D5E27 100%);
        /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #4C9444), color-stop(1, #2D5E27));
        /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4C9444 0%, #2D5E27 100%);
        /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */ 
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #4C9444 0%, #2D5E27 100%);
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
        color:white;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-top:30px;
        float:right;
    }

    .light-gray-section .content {
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        clear:both;
    }
```

I want the line to fill in 100% of the space (minus margins) between the h1 and the button on the right, but the killer is that I need to allow the h1 and the button content to change (in my asp.net application) which may very well change their width, so I cannot hardcode any widths into them.  All solutions I have found for similar layouts involve hard coding the widths into the left and right elements.

I hope this code works out of context, lol.  Right now, of course I have the width of the line in the middle hard coded to 100px just so that it will appear in the right place and I can still see it.  When I try width:100%, it becomes as wide as the containing section and falls to the next line and pushes the button to the line after that.

I hope I do not have to resort to table cells... I assume this might work if I set the middle cell to have a width of 100% (although I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML, the "green-button" tag should come before the line tag(both floats must come first), and don't specify a `width` but add `overflow: hidden` instead.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M3Lt4/

Comment: Hmmm... now I am confused... this works perfectly in your fiddle, but not in my application.  It seems there might be some other css messing it up somewhere.  I will have to figure out what that is.  But great answer!  I will mark it as the correct answer and then get on to figuring out what is messing it up elsewhere in my css.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I never knew about jsfiddle.net before.  Love it.  Thanks for showing me!

Comment: Oh!  It was just that I hadn't deleted the rest of the CSS crap that I had in there for the line div in my actual application. Most notably display:inline-block;.  Cool!

Comment: Yep jsfiddle.net is very useful to debug this kind of problem. You can use it when posting a question too :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this ..

```
<section id="recent-news-posts" class="light-gray-section">
<h1>
    <div class="h1-first">
        Recent
    </div>
    <div class="h1-second">
        NewsPosts
    </div>

</h1>
<!--div class="line">&nbsp;</div-->
<br /><hr align="center" width = "88%" size="1" />
<div class="green-button">Read All News</div>
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't want to work when the width of the h1 and the button combined is bigger than 12% of the width.  The line and button both fall below the previous elements.  I need to not have to know what percentage to put in there.  (Also, changing from using a div with a border to using an hr doesn't buy my anything.)